# Can I disconnect a HTTP connection to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) every time?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

The point of my question is about "TCP connections flow" between my application server and Google Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) server.
I plan that my application disconnect a TCP connection every time for each
HTTP request
and response. (This behavior is like HTTP/1.0).
However, I can't find related mentions about it on FCM's web pages.
(FCM web page (relating legacy HTTP Protocol) has a illustration about communication flow, but I want one about HTTP Protocol).

This is outside of the scope of FCM specifications, for an example,
Apple Notification Service (APNs) specification request that a tcp
connection
must not disconnect while the connection is fine. (If I eagerly want to disconnect, I have been requested once a day by ANPs specification).

Can I disconnect the connection for every HTTP communication with FCM ?
I am worried about that FCM will guess that this behavior is DDoS attack.
However, my application does not repeat connection fast like DDoS attack.

Please excuse my poor English.
Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Cloud Messaging legacy HTTP API is a connectionless protocol. You can either establish a new connection for each request, or reuse an existing connection, as you see fit.

That said, I'd recommend re-using the connection where possible, especially if you expect a high number of requests. This both optimizes throughput, and prevents current or future misclassification as malware.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you Frank.
I agree with your suggestion about re-using the connection.
Also your suggestion about "misclassification as malware" make sense.
I consider reusing connections if possible.